# How can I programatically take a screenshot of the entire app?

Tags: android

I'm working on UI automation tests for an Android app. I need to save off a screenshot of the app as it appears during various steps of the test for later analysis by test engineers.

The usual way to do this in Android is to get the Window, then get the DecorView, then call onDraw with a Canvas backed by a Bitmap and save the Bitmap. This doesn't work when a Dialog is showing on top of an Activity, however. The Dialog and Activity each have their own separate DecorView.

Is there any way to programatically take a screenshot of the entire app with all windows composited? Unfortunately, the device is not rooted and the app does not have signature permissions, so this answer in another thread does not apply:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837910/244521

Answer (score 1):

For phone devices: [This article](http://lifehacker.com/5994516/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-android/all) shares some tips that might help. However, on ICS and above, you may need to use Home + Power, not Volume Down + Power, as the article says.

For automated tests, perhaps [AutomatedScreenshots](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/AutomatedScreenshots) will help

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I'm not talking about a user working with a phone, I'm talking about code running in a test class, like this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html